# MetaUML: via emp package for LaTeX gives no output

Tags: emp, metauml

The following example prints only the figure's caption:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{emp}
\ifx\pdftexversion\undefined
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\else
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{empfile}
\begin{empcmds}
input metauml;
\end{empcmds}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{emp}[classdiag](20, 20)
Class.A("A")()();
Class.B("B")()();
B.e = A.w + (-20, 0);
drawObjects(A, B);
link(inheritance)(B.e -- A.w);
\end{emp}
\caption{A class diagram}
\end{figure}
\end{empfile}

\end{document}
```

Environment: Ubuntu 11.04 (amd64), TexLive 2009, MetaUML 0.2.5, TeXMaker 2.2.1.

**EDIT**:

Here's full example with replacement of `\ifx ... \fi` with suggestion based on `ifpdf` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{emp}
\usepackage{ifpdf,graphicx}
\ifpdf
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{empfile}
\begin{empcmds}
input metauml;
\end{empcmds}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{emp}[classdiag](20, 20)
Class.A("A")()();
Class.B("B")()();
B.e = A.w + (-20, 0);
drawObjects(A, B);
link(inheritance)(B.e -- A.w);
\end{emp}
\caption{A class diagram}
\end{figure}
\end{empfile}

\end{document}
```

Processing still gives no graphical output. Only figure's caption is printed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be testing pdflatex compilation as you do in the code from `\ifx` up to `\fi`, but rather with

```
\usepackage{ifpdf,graphicx}
\ifpdf
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi
```

You can also use the gmp package

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{mpost}[mpsettings=input metauml;]
Class.A("A")()();
Class.B("B")()();
B.e = A.w + (-20, 0);
drawObjects(A, B);
link(inheritance)(B.e -- A.w);
\end{mpost}
\caption{A class diagram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape`. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of the package.)

Comment: Does `pdflatex -shell-escape` relate to the answer based on `ifpdf`? I've replaced `\ifx ... \fi` with corresponding code, but nothing have changed.

Comment: @Dmitry: No, for the emp solution it's not necessary to call pdflatex with `-shell-escape`. I've processed your input (with the suggested code change) with latex and pdflatex, getting the expected result.

Comment: I've edited my question adding (follow EDIT subsection) full example code with changes accordingly to your first suggestion. There must something tricky.

Comment: Nothing tricky: you have to run Metapost on the `.mp` file you get after the LaTeX run. If your file is called `dmitry.tex`, then there is a file called `dmitry.mp`; do `mpost dmitry` and run LaTeX again.

Comment: Being a little bit familiar with LaTeX and TikZ, I am very new to MetaPost. So, I've totally messed up with a plenty of new tools I should know about. You helped me so much! Thank you! I think I'll adopt using your package.

Comment: @egreg Your package is not in TexLive? When I try to compile your given code I get `gmp.sty not found` and even when I change it to `emp`.

Comment: @user230137 Yes, it is; but if you don't have a full distribution, you may not have it. What distribution are you running?

Comment: Ok I haven't installed Texlive Metapost packages.