# No output using MetaUML and emp

Tags: errors, metauml, emp

I tried using MetaUML to create UML diagrams for my LaTeX file, but for some reason, I do not get an output. Still, TEXnicCenter 2.02 (64bit) compiles without error.

I already tried a [previous suggestion from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17237/metauml-via-emp-package-for-latex-gives-no-output), but it still doesn't produce anything.

I used the following code:

```
\usepackage{emp}
\usepackage{ifpdf,graphicx}
\ifpdf
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{empfile}
\begin{empcmds}
input metauml;
\end{empcmds}
```

and in my chapter file, I used the following:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{emp}[classdiag2](20, 20)
Class.A("A")()();
Class.B("B")()();
B.e = A.w + (-20, 0);
drawObjects(A, B);
link(inheritance)(B.e -- A.w);
\end{emp}
\caption[Algorithm concep2t]{The concept of the algorithm}
\label{fig:algorithmConcept2}
\end{figure}
```

Could the problem be due to the fact that the actual code for the figure is in a seperate .tex file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `mpost` on the produced file, the `emp` package doesn't do it automatically.

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{emp}
\usepackage{ifpdf,graphicx}
\ifpdf
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{empfile}
\begin{empcmds}
input metauml;
\end{empcmds}
\begin{emp}[classdiag2](20, 20)
Class.A("A")()();
Class.B("B")()();
B.e = A.w + (-20, 0);
drawObjects(A, B);
link(inheritance)(B.e -- A.w);
\end{emp}
\end{empfile}

\caption[Algorithm concep2t]{The concept of the algorithm}
\label{fig:algorithmConcept2}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I save this document as `boboaut.tex` and compile it, I find a file `boboaut.mp` in the same directory (it's immaterial if the code for the `figure` environment is in a separate file you load with `\input` or `\include`). Then you must open a command window and run `mpost boboaut.mp` in it. You don't need to do this every time, but only when you add or modify MetaUML graphs. Note that with more than one of them you should name the output `.mp` file with

```
\begin{empfile}[<meaningful name>]
```

where `<meaningful name>` might be the same as the argument to `\label`, for instance. You have to manually run every produced `.mp` file.

Having a `\begin{empfile}` at the start and `\end{empfile}` at the end is not recommendable, because it would mean compiling the whole document in a group, which is *bad*.

[image]

Note that there are TikZ libraries for UML diagrams, look in the site for them. They're much more powerful than MetaUML with `emp`.

Comment: I looked at TikZ for UML but apparently it does not support activity diagrams, which I actually need.

But thanks for your answer!